# Using CQL filter to query date relative to present

Tags: cql, geoserver

I'm working with geoserver ,and i want to filter my layer by date (WFS),
i have two columns : Date_start and Date_end

i would like to display only feature that verify this condition :
**Date_PRESENT >Date_start  and Date_PRESENT<Date_end**

where Date_PRESENT is the current date and time.
i dont wanna  put today's date in manually,I want to do it based on the present without a need to adjust the CQL filter.

Following the docs regarding temporal predicates, I can get close:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html#temporal-predicate
But i can't find how to get the current date

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try with `now() > Date_Start and now() < Date_End`

See also the full CQL function reference:
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#temporal-functions